# How to fetch data from oracle data base from another computer

Tags: oracle, listener, tns

I am trying to execute one simple desktop application in my system that is built upon java swing.
This application fetches the data from the oracle database which is present in computer A.

I did the development in computer A and built its jar and kept the jar in another system.
I have started all the services of oracle and created an ad hoc network between the two systems, but I am not able to execute the application from another computer. I googled a lot and did the mentioned changes. Still I am getting the same error of TNS listener.

```
IOException: The network adapter could not establish the connection.
```

finally I thought to put my code here. please look at the below code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection connection =     
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/XE"
                                 ,"system"
                                 ,"system"    );
```

Please help me on this.

I have also tried modifying the tnsnames.ora file but was not helpful. can anybody please help me on this.

Comment: Can you ping the targer server?  Can you then tnsping the target database?

Answer (score 0):

Check the listener.ora file - what is the IP address the service is binding to, i.e. what is the IP address specified in this file? If 127.0.0.1, that will explain why it works on Computer A but not B.

If this is the case you should fist stop teh listener service, backup the listener.ora, edit listener.ora, changing the IP address to the appropriate one for Computer A (accessible from Computer B), restart the listener, and retry.

Use tnsping to test the connection works, if you don't have TNS ping you can try "Telnet hostname port" (e.g. telnet computer-A 1521) and if it returns  blank screen and flashing cursor on top left then the service is up.

Comment: Hi,
I tried this solution but it did'nt worked, I opened the listener.ora file and made the below changes. 
   LISTENER =(DESCRIPTION_LIST =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)(PORT =1521))))
still iam getting the same error, when i tried with telnet hostname 1521 it returns me error saying that "failed to connect".
below is my tnsnames.ora files changes
XE =(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = XE)
))

Comment: Can you "telnet localhost 1521" on your Computer A? 
After making the changes did you restart the listener? 
IS the firewall running preventing inbound connection on port 1521, or rather do you need to add an exception for TNS on the firewall? 
Have tried disabling the firewall?
If you're using Java thin the TNSNAMES.ORA shouldn't matter as you supply the relevant details directly in the connection string - that's why the thin driver doesn't need a Oracle client install.
Perhaps if you posted the following info it would help - outputs from ipconfig on both PCs, listener.ora, netstat -an.

Comment: Hi I tried this solution as well.Below is the Listener.ora file.

    SID_LIST_LISTENER =(SID_LIST =(SID_DESC =(SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)       (ORACLE_HOME = F:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc))(SID_DESC =(SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)))
    LISTENER =(DESCRIPTION_LIST =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL     = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =     192.168.137.220)(PORT = 1521))))
   DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

Comment: output of telnet localhost 1521 :
F:\Users\saish pole>telnet localhost 1521
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1521: Connect failed
IPConfig: Computer B---192.168.137.1
IPConfig: Computer A----192.168.137.220
Also, After making changes in the listner.ora file my actual code stopped working in the computer A itself and started giving the same error.
how ever before modifying the listner.ora file the the telnet localhost 1521 was working.

Comment: Also please note that we have created one adhoce network for these two pCS to communicate.

Comment: below is my connection code:

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           Connection connection =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.137.220:152    1/XE","system","system");

Comment: Typically, "localhost" resolves to 127.0.0.1. Each PC has a localhost address which resolves to 127.0.0.1. If you have the listener running on 127.0.0.1 it can only be accessed locally. You haven't said whether you can PING each PC from the other. If you can, have you checked the firewall on computer A?